# re-development of Chrome webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, chromium

I hear that webdriver for Chrome is being re-developed as part of the Chromium project (since the original Chrome webdriver of the selenium project is unusable).  Does anyone know if development is complete?  If so, where can I find the jars?  Has it been pushed to maven central yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new Chrome driver has been checked into the Chromium project tree, and the binaries made available on the [Selenium project site](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list). The individual language bindings for the Chrome driver will still be included in the Selenium downloads. Information about what is required to run the new Chrome driver can be found in the [project wiki](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver). Note that Chrome 12.0.712.0 or higher is required to work with the new Chrome driver.

The .jars, as of this writing, are not available yet in any Maven repository. You can expect that to change when the next public release of the compiled sources is available. In the interim, you can build from the [latest sources](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/BuildingWebDriver) yourself.